# Getting error when using Java 8's lambda expression in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, lambda, java-8

Recently I upgraded my Spring web application to Java 8, and replaced some expressions to lambda form.

ex)

```
for (int i : integerList) { ... }
```

to

```
integerList.forEach((i) -> { ... })
```

It compiles without error but when I try to mount the app on Tomcat, I get error as follow :

```
17:25:12.358 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ium/concerto/config/ConcertoRepositoryConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/Users/daehee/projects/ium-concerto/target/classes/
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
```

The error stops popping after changing lambda expression to for the old-fashioned loop.

I'm currently using Java 8 (Java 1.8), Spring Framework 4, Hibernate 3.6.9.Final and the latest version of Tomcat 7 (7.0.53). The runtime environment of Tomcat is Java 8, of course.

Comment: if you use eclipse, try changing the generated class file compatibility to java 7

Comment: yogx/ I can't use lambda in java 7

Comment: i know that... Just try changing the generated class file compatibility to java 7. Go to eclipse  - > preferences - > java -> Compiler and there you can find the option to do so

Comment: I tried, but changing .class file compatibility to 1.7 requires source file compatibility to stay below 1.8 also, which results another compile error. (Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above)

Comment: I believe you need to run Tomcat 8 to support lambda syntax.